# Youtube doesn't stream videos when accessed from the Youtube portal

Tags: 14.04, flash, youtube

I've been facing a strange problem with the flash/youtube. Firstly, I noticed that I wasn't able to stream videos other than the 360p, so I tried to fix it, installing the PepperFlash, like is told here:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/install-pepper-flash-chromium-ubuntu-14-04

Now I can stream videos with better quality 720p and 1080p, but it doesn't if I go directly to youtube site.

Let me explain:
If i go to wwww.youtube.com search for a video it won't stream, it stays stuck at 0:00.
However if I go to www.google.com and search for that same video, the google will redirect me to youtube website and video will stream naturally.

Does anyone know what might the pŕoblem?
Thanks.

P.S: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Way**

Open *Totem Movie Player* and press `F9`

[image: Totem Movie Player]

Comment: It does work, but wouldn't you how to actually fix this problem?